# Execute a list of completable futures only if the previous one throws an exception

Tags: java, future, completable-future

I have a list of completable futures and I would like to start with the first future and if there are any completion exceptions, I'd like to try the next future in the list and so on until I exhausted all of my futures. If any of the futures succeed, i'd like to stop there without using the next futures in the list. How do I accomplish this? So far, I have tried this:

```
for (SampleFutures future : getSampleFutures()) {

    try {
          return future.someMethod();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          log.error("An exception occurred, Will try the next future.", e);
      }
}
```

But when I was testing this method, I see that when something fails in the future completion exception is thrown and the next set of futures are not tried.

Edit:

This is how SampleFtures look like

```
public class SampleFutureA implements SampleFutures {

    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<SomeOject> someMethod() {
        return CompletableFuture
                .supplyAsync(() -> someOtherMethod())
                .thenApply( ()->anotherMethod())
                .exceptionally(ex -> exceptionHandler(ex));
    }
```

Comment: I'm not throwing any exception here again in the catch block right? So why do we need an explicit continue again ? @deHaar

Comment: try storing the value of future.someMethod within your for loop instead of returning immediately. Once you have determined there is no exception, return the value of this variable.

Comment: What is `SampleFutures` and what does `someMethod()` return?

Comment: I'm thinking of using 

```try {
          SomeObject someObect =  future.someMethod().get();
          return someObject;
      } catch (Exception e) {
          log.error("An exception occurred, Will try the next future.", e);
      }```

But this seems like not an async way. Wondering if there are any better options out there.

Comment: Looks to me you are misusing exceptions for flow control here. Maybe better to encapsulate the need for trying the next future in the return value.

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of issue for which I would recommend using [EA Async](https://github.com/electronicarts/ea-async) as it provides a kind of async/await mecanism that makes it very easy to implement this:

Initialize async when your application starts: (you can also pre-process the application, read [the documentation](https://github.com/electronicarts/ea-async#instrumenting-your-code) for details)

```
Async.init();
```

then use `await()` as follows:

```
for (SampleFutures future : getSampleFutures()) {
    try {
        return completedFuture(await(future.someMethod()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("An exception occurred, Will try the next future.", e);
    }
}
throw new RuntimeException("All futures failed!");
```

However, if you cannot or do not want to use it, you can implement the same thing with a recursive asynchronous method:

```
private CompletableFuture<SomeObject> processNext(Iterator<SampleFutures> iterator) {
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
        return iterator.next().someMethod()
                .handle((r, e) -> {
                    if (e != null) {
                        log.error("An exception occurred, Will try the next future.", e);
                        return processNext(iterator);
                    } else {
                        return completedFuture(r);
                    }
                }).thenCompose(c -> c);
    }
    CompletableFuture<SomeObject> allFailed = new CompletableFuture<>();
    allFailed.completeExceptionally(new RuntimeException("All futures failed!"));
    return allFailed;
}
```

that you call with

```
return processNext(getSampleFutures().iterator());
```

This method will call the first future, and only when it fails, it will recursively call itself aynchronously which will call the next ones.

We are unfortunately forced to implement it with `hande()` + `thenCompose(c -> c)` because there is no "compose" version of `handle()` and `exceptionally()`. So `handle()` returns a `CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<SampleObject>>` and `thenCompose()` just unwraps it.